# Gradle Project Sync Failed on latest android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed the latest Android studio and am getting a gradle project sync failed when I start a new project:

[image]

build.gradel file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

When i added:

```
 compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

I got this error:

[image]

Comment: Post your gradle file content

Comment: my build.gradel file?

Comment: Do you have jdk 7 installed?

Comment: Oh..just noticed the error..you need JDK 7 installed.

Comment: How do I install that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your build.gradle.

```
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

inside `android { }`

Trageting Android 21 requires JavaVersion 1.7. default is 1.6.

In the case you don't have JDK 7 installed download it from [jdk download site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

## Update

Newer version of **Android Studio** have built-in **OpenJDK  8**, So with newer version of **Android Studio** this error should not exist and You no longer need to download **Oracle JDK** unless you really want.

Comment: Added that then got a new error, added new screenshot to post

Comment: the addition must resolve the problem.It looks like you don't have jdk.download it from link in my answer or a simple google search will lead you to the site then set JAVA_HOME in your Environment Variables.